# how to plot bar graph of lantitude longitude with respect to time in python using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have csv file with attributes latitude, longitude, date and time. i want to plot no. of visited points vs. time.

```
latitude|longitude|time    | date
-122.22|33.36    |10:20:12|december 2016
-122.23|33.32    |10:20:12|december 2016
```

how do I calculate number of visited points and make bar graph with respect to time or date by using pandas?

Comment: you need to at least provide some code or some attempt

Answer (score 0):

First date and time needs to be converted to proper format.
Like for example time can be converted to "datetime64" format using following code.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).apply(pd.Timestamp)
```

> Caution :: here date is assumed to be 1/1/1900

output will be something like,

```
1900-01-01 10:21:12
```

Then you can use groupby to count the latitude and longitude visited at perticular time.

```
df.groupby(["latitude","longitude","time"]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

Output (I have assumed sample data by copying your data multiple times)

```
   latitude  longitude                time  count
0   -122.23      33.32 1900-01-01 10:20:12      5
1   -122.22      33.32 1900-01-01 10:21:12     10
2   -122.22      33.32 1900-01-01 11:21:12     10
3   -122.22      33.36 1900-01-01 10:20:12      5
```

Now you can use this new data frame to plot bar charts or other charts as per requirement.